# overflow-x hides content (and it cannot be overwritten)

Tags: html, css

I have used the following style inside the  element of my html to get rid of the extra white space on the right side of the screen:

```
<style>
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow-x: hidden;

    }
</style>
```

And it worked perfectly fine. However, it sets the visibility of some of the content on of the pages to be "hidden" and I have tried using the !important attribute to overwrite but no matter what I do, they remain invisible.

```
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="icon"><a href=""><i>

                    <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" src="/img/yusufImg/slope%20design.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">


                </i></a></div>
                <h4 class="title"><a href="">Slope Design</a></h4>
                <a id="slopeButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success" style="font-weight: 900;color: white;">Read More</a>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div style=" visibility:visible !important;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="icon"><a href=""><i>

                    <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" src="/img/yusufImg/taş%20duvar.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">


                </i></a></div>
                <h4 class="title"><a href="">Tas Duvar</a></h4>
                <a id="tasduvarButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline- 
success" style="font-weight: 900;color: white;">Read More</a>


            </div>
```

Ones with the inline style for visibility have the same exact attributes and classes as the ones that don't. However, they are always rendered to be invisible when I load the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `<div style="overflow-x: visible;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">`

Comment: That deosnt work either unfortunately.

Comment: I have also tried putting them in a different row, inside and outside of the current row. It is a total nightmare.

Comment: The html and body should never need overflow rules like that. If you have a white space it's likely a problem in your CSS somewhere.